# Network request failed with fetch method in React Native for Rapid API

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api, rapidapi

I am developing an app in react native.

I would like to make a call to RapidAPI, such as:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jokes-by-api-ninjas.p.rapidapi.com/v1/jokes", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'myapi',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'jokes-by-api-ninjas.p.rapidapi.com'
      }
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, []);
```

I am getting this error: `[TypeError: Network request failed]`.

I also tried with the axios package and led to the same thing.

I used the python snippet from Rapid API and it worked strait away.

What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT:

I changed `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to true in my Info.plist, then rebuilt with `npx react-native run-ios`, still no luck.

In the following code:

```
const url = 'https://jokes-by-api-ninjas.p.rapidapi.com/v1/jokes';
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': '79274b9cbamsh648fe97da3e476dp167e86jsnb80a57f2cac5',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'jokes-by-api-ninjas.p.rapidapi.com'
      }
    };

    // const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
    // const options = {
    //   method: 'GET',
    //   headers: {
    //     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    //     'Dummy-Header': 'TestValue' // Custom dummy header for testing
    //   }
    // };
    
    fetch(url, options)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((resJson) => {
          console.log(resJson)
          resolve()
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log('Error in getAddressFromCoordinates', e)
        resolve()
      })
```

First url/option fail and second works. How ?

Comment: I take it since it's a react-native app you have no way of getting a more useful error message than that?

Comment: can you check it manually with postman?

Comment: Just made it work in Postman fine

Answer (score 1):

React Native uses the fetch API, which might behave differently from Python's requests library. Try using the https module in React Native to make the request.

Install `https` module, and

```
import https from 'https';

useEffect(() => {
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'myapi',
      'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'jokes-by-api-ninjas.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
  };

  const req = https.request('https://jokes-by-api-ninjas.p.rapidapi.com/v1/jokes', options, (response) => {
    let data = '';

    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', () => {
      console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    });
  });

  req.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });

  req.end();
}, []);
```

The problem here also could be that iOS does not allow HTTP requests by default, only HTTPS. If you want to enable HTTP requests add this to your info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: still not working